# Permission issue starting mongo from a script

Tags: bash, mongodb, sudo

If I run the following command, everything works as expected:

```
sudo mongod --fork --dbpath /path/to_data/ --port 27027 --syslog
```

However, if I put the following command in startmongo.sh and run it with sudo, I get an error:

```
mongod --fork --dbpath /path/to_data/ --port 27027 --syslog
```

Error:

```
[root@server Folder]# sudo ./startmongo.sh
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 2394
ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 100
To see additional information in this output, start without the "--fork" option.
```

If I look at the log file I see the following:

> STORAGE [initandlisten] exception in initAndListn: Location28596: Unable to determine status of lock file in the data directory /path/to_data/: boost::filesystem::status: Permission denied: "/path/tod_data/mongod.lock", terminating

So how can I start Mongo from a script?

Comment: are you using the command  " su " too?

Comment: no. I listed everything I'm doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
--fork

    Enables a daemon mode that runs the mongod process in the background. By default mongod does not run as a daemon: typically you will run mongod as a daemon, either by using --fork or by using a controlling process that handles the daemonization process (e.g. as with upstart and systemd).
```

So when you using fork without using sudo effective uid don't have permission.

Edit: So I mean, if you don't want to daemonize process you should use nohup with `&` and mange everything within script. With your logs `data directory /path/to_data/: boost::filesystem::status: Permission denied` mean newly spawned process don't have permission to access files or data. Here `--fork` is doing something interesting so it doesn't work as you mentioned above.

You can try two options:

1. Use like `nohup mongod --fork --dbpath /path/to_data/ --port 27027 --syslog &`
2. Add sudo within script or directly call upstart or systemd file from script.

Hope this will help.

Comment: I don't understand. I'm not running the mongod command with sudo, but I am running the shell script with sudo.  What is the difference and *how do I fix it*?

Comment: Updated my answer, hope I understand your question correctly.

Comment: `nohup` seems to have done what I needed.  Thanks!